# Simplifying for loops that includes conditions with better linq queries

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

The code below selects all items that are locked. How can I optimise it?
`ShopItemData` doesn't contain a field for locked/unlocked.

`_allItems` is a `ShopItemData[]`

`_codaCommonShopItems`, `_codaRareShopItems`, and `_codaEpicShopItems` are `CodaShopItem[]`s.

```
public class CodaShopItem : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Button _itemButton;
        private bool _inUse;
        private int _itemId;
        private CodaShopScreen.ItemRarity _itemRarity;

        public int ItemId => _itemId;
        public bool Unlocked;
        public bool InUse => _inUse;
        public CodaShopScreen.ItemRarity ItemRarity => _itemRarity;
}

public class ShopItemData : ScriptableObject
    {
        public int ItemId;
        public Sprite ItemSprite;
        public CodaShopScreen.ItemRarity ItemRarity;
        public GameObject InGamePrefab;
        public GameObject PreviewPrefab;
    }


public IEnumerable<ShopItemData> GetLockedItems()
        {
            var lockedCommonItems = _codaCommonShopItems.Where(item => !item.Unlocked).ToArray();
            var lockedRareItems = _codaRareShopItems.Where(item => !item.Unlocked).ToArray();
            var lockedEpicItems = _codaEpicShopItems.Where(item => !item.Unlocked).ToArray();
            var allLockedItems = new List<ShopItemData>();
            var allItemDatas = GetAllItems().ToArray();
            
            for (var i = 0; i < lockedCommonItems.Length; i++)
            {
                var lockedItemData = allItemDatas.First(item => item.ItemId == lockedCommonItems[i].ItemId && item.ItemRarity == lockedCommonItems[i].ItemRarity);
                allLockedItems.Add(lockedItemData);
            }
            
            for (var i = 0; i < lockedRareItems.Length; i++)
            {
                var lockedItemData = allItemDatas.First(item => item.ItemId == lockedRareItems[i].ItemId && item.ItemRarity == lockedRareItems[i].ItemRarity);
                allLockedItems.Add(lockedItemData);
            }
            
            for (var i = 0; i < lockedEpicItems.Length; i++)
            {
                var lockedItemData = allItemDatas.First(item => item.ItemId == lockedEpicItems[i].ItemId && item.ItemRarity == lockedEpicItems[i].ItemRarity);
                allLockedItems.Add(lockedItemData);
            }

            return allLockedItems;
        }

public IEnumerable<ShopItemData> GetAllItems()
        {
            return _allItems;
        }
```

And this is how shop items are created

```
private void CreateCommonShopItems()
        {
            var commonItems = Resources.LoadAll<ShopItemData>(ShopItemDataPath).Where(item => item.ItemRarity == ItemRarity.Common);
            var commonCategory = _itemCategories.First(item => item.ItemRarity == ItemRarity.Common);
            commonCategory.Create(ref _codaCommonShopItems, commonItems.ToArray());
        }
```

basically I am getting the item datas and passing  them into another function which turns them into `_codaCommonShopItem` and fill their properties

```
_codaCommonShopItem[i].Init(items[i].ItemId, items[i].ItemRarity, items[i].ItemSprite);
```

Comment: Please include `GetAllItems` code, and for simplicity, explain the releationship between `_codaCommonShopItems` and `_codaRareShopItems` and `_codaEpicShopItems` (you can provide their models or any related FK between them.

Comment: Just for starter, if they have common `FK`, a simple `JOIN` would solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, i have added more details about those classes @iSR5

Comment: I couldn't use join to make it easier, maybe because i am not very familiar with linq queries.

Comment: do `_codaCommonShopItems`, `_codaRareShopItems` and `_codaEpicShopItems` use `ShopItemData` as source ?  if yes, then you can combine their logic (the `Where` conditions) with `!item.Unlocked` to get all of them from the data-source directly.

Comment: Yes ShopItemData is the class that i am using to get the item info then pass it to CodaShopItem class. But the ShopItemData doesn't contain the locked/unlocked property.

Comment: Could you show the query of the CodaCommon, CodaRare, and CodaEpic ? I need to see how to get them from ShopItemData.

Comment: They are just arrays of CodaShopItem and i am filling their properties from the data i am getting from ShopItemData model class. Added more detail.

Comment: Thank you, now it's almost clear to me what's going on. You didn't mention that `ItemRarity` is an `enum` object.

Comment: you can replace `GetLockedItems` code with this line `return _allItems.Where(item => !item.Unlocked && (item.ItemRarity == ItemRarity.Common || item.ItemRarity == ItemRarity.Rare || item.ItemRarity == ItemRarity.Epic))?.ToArray();`

Comment: Thanks @iSR5 but ShopItemData doesn't have a field for Unlocked thats why i am matching each CodaShopItem with ShopItemData by their item ids.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short terms, you can do this :

```
public IEnumerable<ShopItemData> GetLockedItems()
{
    var allLockedItems = new List<ShopItemData>();
    
    allLockedItems.AddRange(_codaCommonShopItems.Where(item => !item.Unlocked));
    allLockedItems.AddRange(_codaRareShopItems.Where(item => !item.Unlocked));
    allLockedItems.AddRange(_codaEpicShopItems.Where(item => !item.Unlocked));
    
    var result = _allItems
                    .Join(allLockedItems, 
                    items  => items.ItemId, 
                    locked => locked.ItemId,
                    (items, locked) => new { AllItems = items, LockedItems = locked })
                    .Where(x => x.AllItems.ItemId == x.LockedItems.ItemId && x.AllItems.ItemRarity == x.LockedItems.ItemRarity)
                    .Select(x=> new ShopItemData
                    {
                        ItemId = AllItems.ItemId,                       
                        ItemSprite = AllItems.ItemSprite,
                        ItemRarity = AllItems.ItemRarity, 
                        InGamePrefab = AllItems.InGamePrefab, 
                        PreviewPrefab = AllItems.PreviewPrefab
                    });

    return result;
}
```

So, you add all unlocked items in the list, then join the new list with the `_allItems` on the same condition you use.

What I suggest, is to make a child class that would flatten and combine both objects properties. something like this :

```
private class JoinedShopItemData
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public bool Unlocked { get; set; }

    public bool InUse { get; set; }

    public CodaShopScreen.ItemRarity ItemRarity { get; set; }

    public Sprite ItemSprite { get; set; }

    public GameObject InGamePrefab { get; set; }

    public GameObject PreviewPrefab { get; set; }
}
```

then, you can initialize this object in your constructor, and prepare it to be used as filtered source of `_allItems` for the current class.

Something like :

```
private IEnumerable<JoinedShopItemData> GetJoinedShopItemData(IEnumerable<CodaShopItem> source)
{
    foreach(var coda in source)
    {
        foreach(var item in _allItems)
        {
            if(item.ItemId == coda.ItemId && item.ItemRarity == coda.ItemRarity)
            {
                yield return new JoinedShopItemData
                {
                    ItemId          = AllItems.ItemId,                      
                    ItemSprite      = AllItems.ItemSprite,
                    ItemRarity      = AllItems.ItemRarity, 
                    InGamePrefab    = AllItems.InGamePrefab, 
                    PreviewPrefab   = AllItems.PreviewPrefab, 
                    Unlocked        = LockedItems.Unlocked, 
                    InUse           = LockedItems.InUse     
                }; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or use linq (like the first example)
Now, assuming you'll have a global `List<JoinedShopItemData>` named `_joinedShopItemData` that will hold  `GetJoinedShopItemData` results.

In this case, your `GetLockedItems` method would be :

```
public IEnumerable<ShopItemData> GetLockedItems()
{
    return _joinedShopItemData
    .Where(item => !item.Unlocked && (item.ItemRarity == ItemRarity.Common || item.ItemRarity == ItemRarity.Rare || item.ItemRarity == ItemRarity.Epic))
    .Select(item => new ShopItemData 
    {
        ItemId = item.ItemId,                       
        ItemSprite = item.ItemSprite,
        ItemRarity = item.ItemRarity, 
        InGamePrefab = item.InGamePrefab, 
        PreviewPrefab = item.PreviewPrefab
    }).ToArray();
}
```

This will elemnate the need of creating a separate collection for each property condition (like `_codaCommonShopItems`, `_codaRareShopItems` ..etc.). As you will always have a joined object which you can access easily.